# Bad credentials when logging in - Symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony, orm, yaml

I keep getting the Bad Credentials error when I try to login. I did everything to find a solution, but I can't seem to find my mistake. Is there something wrong in my security.yml?

User Entity:

```
namespace Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="username_UNIQUE", columns={"username"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_email_UNIQUE", columns={"user_email"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_users_persons1", columns={"person_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_users_roles1_idx", columns={"role_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=60, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userEmail;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_rating", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $userRating;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $userCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userModified;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userDeleted;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_lastlogin", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userLastlogin;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_locked", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userLocked;

    /**
     * @var \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Persons
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Persons")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="person_id", unique=true)
     * })
     */
    private $person;

    /**
     * @var \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Roles
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Roles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="role_id")
     * })
     */
    private $role;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
    }

    /**
     * Set userId
     *
     * @param integer $userId
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserId($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Set userEmail
     *
     * @param string $userEmail
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserEmail($userEmail)
    {
        $this->userEmail = $userEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userEmail
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserEmail()
    {
        return $this->userEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Set userRating
     *
     * @param integer $userRating
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserRating($userRating)
    {
        $this->userRating = $userRating;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userRating
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUserRating()
    {
        return $this->userRating;
    }

    /**
     * Set userCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userCreated
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserCreated($userCreated)
    {
        $this->userCreated = $userCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserCreated()
    {
        return $this->userCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set userModified
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userModified
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserModified($userModified)
    {
        $this->userModified = $userModified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userModified
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserModified()
    {
        return $this->userModified;
    }

    /**
     * Set userDeleted
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userDeleted
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserDeleted($userDeleted)
    {
        $this->userDeleted = $userDeleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userDeleted
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserDeleted()
    {
        return $this->userDeleted;
    }

    /**
     * Set userLastlogin
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userLastlogin
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserLastlogin($userLastlogin)
    {
        $this->userLastlogin = $userLastlogin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userLastlogin
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserLastlogin()
    {
        return $this->userLastlogin;
    }

    /**
     * Set userLocked
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userLocked
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserLocked($userLocked)
    {
        $this->userLocked = $userLocked;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userLocked
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserLocked()
    {
        return $this->userLocked;
    }

    /**
     * Set person
     *
     * @param \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Persons $person
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPerson(\Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Persons $person = null)
    {
        $this->person = $person;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get person
     *
     * @return \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Persons
     */
    public function getPerson()
    {
        return $this->person;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Roles $role
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setRoles(\Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Roles $role = null)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return \Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
        //return $this->role;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials(){
    }
}
```

UserController with register action:

```
    public function registerAction(Request $request){

        if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))
        {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('reuzze_reuzze_homepage'));
        }

        $user = new Users();

        $person = new Persons();

        $address = new Addresses();

        $region = new Regions();

        $role = new Roles();

        $address->setRegion($region);

        $user->setPerson($person);
        $user->setUserRating('1');
        $user->setRoles($role);

        $person->setAddress($address);

        $address->setRegion($region);

        $role->setRoleName('Student');

        $form = $this->createForm(new RegisterType(), $user);

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
        {
            $form->bind($request);

            if($form->isValid())
            {
                $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
                $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
                $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getpassword(), $user->getsalt());
                $user->setpassword($password);

                $user->setRoles($role);

                $date = new \DateTime('NOW');

                $user->setuserCreated($date);

                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $entityManager->persist($person);

                $entityManager->persist($user);
                $entityManager->persist($address);
                $entityManager->persist($region);

                $entityManager->persist($role);

                $entityManager->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('reuzze_reuzze_homepage'));
            }
        }

            return $this->render('ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:User:register.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
    }
```

UserController with login action

```
 public function loginAction(Request $request)
        {
            $session = $request->getSession();

            if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
                $error = $request->attributes->get(
                    SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
                );
            } else {
                $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
                $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            }

            return $this->render('ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:User:login.html.twig', array(
                'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
                'error'         => $error,
            ));
        }
    }
```

RegisterType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('person'     , new PersonType())
            ->add('username'   , 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Username',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Username')
            ))
            ->add('userEmail'       , 'email', array(
                'label' => 'Email',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'E-mail address')
            ))
            ->add('password' , 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'first_name' => 'password',
                'second_name' => 'confirm',
                'first_options' => array(
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password'),
                    'label' => 'Password',
                ),
                'second_options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Repeat Password',
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Repeat Password'),
                ),
                'invalid_message' => 'The passwords are not identical!',
            )
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'register';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users',
            'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
        ));
    }
```

Security.yml

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Reuzze\ReuzzeBundle\Entity\Users:
            algorithm: sha512
            encode_as_base64: false

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        users:
          entity: { class: ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:Users, property: username }

    firewalls:
       secured_area:
            pattern:  ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
                #username_parameter: email
                #password_parameter: password
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
           - { path: ^/,         roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
           - { path: ^/login,    roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
           - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
           - { path: ^/logout,   roles: ROLE_USER }
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

Login view

```
{% extends 'ReuzzeReuzzeBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{# {% block header_title %}Home{% endblock %} #}

{% block content %}
    {% if error %}
        <div class="form-error">{{ error.message|trans }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('reuzze_reuzze_login_checkpage') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Routing.yml

```
reuzze_reuzze_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:Default:home }

reuzze_reuzze_registerpage:
    pattern:  /register
    defaults: { _controller: ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:User:register }

reuzze_reuzze_loginpage:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:User:login }

reuzze_reuzze_login_checkpage:
    pattern:  /login_check
    defaults: { _controller: ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:User:loginCheck }

reuzze_reuzze_logoutpage:
    pattern:  /logout
    defaults: { _controller: ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:User:logout }
```

Comment: Please add your routing file as well. ;-) And aren't you missing a custom user provider?

Comment: I have this in my security.yml providers:
        users:
          entity: { class: ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:Users, property: username }

Comment: Imho your missing the `provider` key in your firewall: `provider: users`. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

Comment: I can't seem to follow..

Comment: Have you tried changing the $userId to $id? Since you have used username as the unique identifier, you might not need $userId as an identifier. I have a feeling that for user loading fosuserbundle might look for $id within the User entity, not $userId. Even symfony itself might look for the standard $id attribute of an enitity.I understand that you have defined it as ID in the ORM, but it might be needed at the framework end than the doctrine mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Imho you're missing the provider definition in your firewall:

```
    firewalls:
       secured_area:
            pattern:  ^/
            provider: users
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
```

Comment: Cache is cleared? User gets created with proper salt/hashed password/role in the database on registration? What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: Cache is clear, I have proper hashes, I keep being anonymous, I there is something wrong with my loginAction.

Comment: Did you by chance misstype the password? ;-) Register a user with a simple one for debugging purposes.